# Creating a for loop in a trap doesn't work in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have been trying to create a trap in a script to basically create some logs of a script that has been running in the background.

Whenever I introduce a for loop in the trap, the script stops doing what it is supposed to do:

```
trap 'terminate' 10
...

write_log(){
    local target=$1
    local file="/tmp/"$target"_log.txt"
    local lines=$(cat /tmp/"$target"_log.txt | wc -l)

    printf "Log for $target\n" >> "log.txt"   # This line is printed


    for ((i=1;i<=$lines;i++));                # Nothing in this loop happens
    do                         
        local start_date=$(date -d "$(sed -n ""$i"p") $file | cut -f1")
        local end_date=$(date -d "$sed -n ""$i"p") $file | cut -f2")
        printf "Logged in $start_date, logged out $end_date" > "log.txt"
    done
}

terminate(){
    for target
    do
        echo "In the for loop!"
        end_session "$target"
        write_log "$target"
    done
    exit 0

}
```

When I run my script in the background and kill it with

```
kill -10 (process_id)
```

the script stops, and starts doing the cleanup, until the point where it finds a for loop. When I remove the for loop in terminate() and instead do individual calls to end_session() and write_log(), end_session() works just fine, and write_log() works fine--until it reaches the for loop.

I am probably missing something basic, but I have looked at this for a while now and can't seem to figure out what is happening. Is there any limitation to for loops in traps?

Comment: Do you mean to clobber `log.txt` each time in the loop with `> log.txt`?

Comment: Yes, I intend to add an entry for each time the user has done a specific action

Comment: Is the value of `$lines` greater than zero? Can you verify it by echoing $lines in the write_log() function?

Comment: The comment from Nathan Wilson about `log.txt` in the loop is that each time through the loop you are going to truncate the `log.txt` file and start it again because you used `> log.txt` instead of `>> log.txt`.

Comment: The file that is being read to set the value of lines is written in end_session(). If I don't call end_session(), the value of lines is 0 and the function terminates skipping the loops. However, if I call end_session(), the value of lines is non-zero and the function hangs in the for loop before even echoing "In the for loop!"

Comment: The `terminate` function needs to be defined before the trap call for this to work at all doesn't it? Aside from Jonathan Leffler's answer about arguments that is.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think that as long as `terminate` is defined before a signal occurs, it'll be fine.  After all, if you have `trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15`, it doesn't matter whether `rm` is a function or a command until the trap is triggered, and the shell finds out which it is when the trap is triggered.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, that wasn't my most accurate statement. It would be more accurate to say that the `terminate` function definition must have been executed before the signal is triggered for this to work (so putting things in this order is asking for potential failure if that doesn't happen). Assuming there is nothing between `write_to_log` and `terminate` and the signal is sent after `terminate` is defined this should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

No arguments are passed to `terminate` when it is invoked by the `trap`, so its loop executes zero times (because `for target; do …; done` is a shorthand for `for target in "$@"; do …; done`, and in a function, `"$@"` is the list of arguments to the function, not to the shell script as a whole).

If that's not what you want to have happen, you have to arrange to pass the relevant arguments to `terminate` in the `trap`.  For example, you could pass all the arguments to the script via a global array:

```
args=( "$@" )
```

and inside `terminate`:

```
for target in "${args[@]}"
```

However, what's best depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The function is hanging because the parentheses are messed up in the date commands. Try this:

```
local start_date=$(date -d "$(sed -n ${i}p "$file" | cut -f1)")
local end_date=$(date -d "$(sed -n ${i}p "$file" | cut -f2)")
```

Comment: The doubled up double quotes in the original are peculiar, but the ones in your code are equally as peculiar. What do you think the doubled up double quotes are doing? (It seems to be a common misperception with you and the OP.) Using `"${i}p"` would make sense (and unquoted `${i}p` is OK); using `"$file"` makes sense and protects you from spaces in file names, etc, but using `""$file""` removes that protection.  And since the `write_log` function is never called (at least under my hypothesis), any screw-up in the quoting is immaterial as long as the shell script doesn't contain syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, I meant to protect from spaces in the file name with double quotes. Not double double quotes. Fixed it.